# read from csv, strtod can't read string with numbers

Tags: c, csv, floating-point, strtod

when I read the follow file

```
"X","Pa(X)","Time","pa","xixj","Value"
"X",0,5,0,"0-0","123.814935276"
" ","  "," "," ","0-1","234"
" ","  "," "," ","0-2","100"
" ","  "," "," ","1-0","166"
" ","  "," "," ","1-1","203.0866414"
" ","  "," "," ","1-2","383"
" ","  "," "," ","2-0","186"
" ","  "," "," ","2-1","338"
" ","  "," "," ","2-2","173.0984233"
" ","  ",10,0,"0-0","186.221113"
"  ","  ","  ","  ","0-1","391"
"  ","  ","  ","  ","0-2","64"
"  ","  ","  ","  ","1-0","235"
"  ","  ","  ","  ","1-1","195.7454998"
"  ","  ","  ","  ","1-2","275"
"  ","  ","  ","  ","2-0","218"
"  ","  ","  ","  ","2-1","121"
"  ","  ","  ","  ","2-2","118.0333872"
" ","  ",20,0,"0-0","416.36349977"
" ","  "," "," ","0-1","282"
" ","  "," "," ","0-2","735"
" ","  "," "," ","1-0","278"
" ","  "," "," ","1-1","211.8960279"
" ","  "," "," ","1-2","266"
" ","  "," "," ","2-0","743"
" ","  "," "," ","2-1","224"
" ","  "," "," ","2-2","371.7404745"
```

my code fails read Value column. I use `strtod` but the results are:

```
X "X"
PaX "Pa(X)"
Time "Time" 
pa "pa" 
xixj "xixj" 
Value 0.000000 
start csv 
X "X"
PaX 0
Time 5 
pa 0 
xixj "0-0" 
Value 0.000000 
start csv 
X " "
PaX "  "
Time " " 
pa " " 
xixj "0-1" 
Value 0.000000 
start csv 
X " "
PaX "  "
Time " " 
pa " " 
xixj "0-2" 
Value 0.000000 
start csv 
X " "
PaX "  "
Time " " 
pa " " 
xixj "1-0" 
Value 0.000000 
start csv 
X " "
PaX "  "
Time " " 
pa " " 
xixj "1-1" 
Value 0.000000 
start csv 
X " "
PaX "  "
Time " " 
pa " " 
xixj "1-2" 
Value 0.000000 
start csv 
X " "
PaX "  "
Time " " 
pa " " 
xixj "2-0" 
Value 0.000000 
start csv 
X " "
PaX "  "
Time " " 
pa " " 
xixj "2-1" 
Value 0.000000 
start csv 
X " "
PaX "  "
Time " " 
pa " " 
xixj "2-2" 
Value 0.000000 
start csv 
X " "
PaX "  "
Time 10 
pa 0 
xixj "0-0" 
Value 0.000000 
start csv 
X "  "
PaX "  "
Time "  " 
pa "  " 
xixj "0-1" 
Value 0.000000 
start csv 
X "  "
PaX "  "
Time "  " 
pa "  " 
xixj "0-2" 
Value 0.000000 
start csv 
X "  "
PaX "  "
Time "  " 
pa "  " 
xixj "1-0" 
Value 0.000000 
start csv 
X "  "
PaX "  "
Time "  " 
pa "  " 
xixj "1-1" 
Value 0.000000 
start csv 
X "  "
PaX "  "
Time "  " 
pa "  " 
xixj "1-2" 
Value 0.000000 
start csv 
X "  "
PaX "  "
Time "  " 
pa "  " 
xixj "2-0" 
Value 0.000000 
start csv 
X "  "
PaX "  "
Time "  " 
pa "  " 
xixj "2-1" 
Value 0.000000 
start csv 
X "  "
PaX "  "
Time "  " 
pa "  " 
xixj "2-2" 
Value 0.000000 
start csv 
X " "
PaX "  "
Time 20 
pa 0 
xixj "0-0" 
Value 0.000000 
start csv 
X " "
PaX "  "
Time " " 
pa " " 
xixj "0-1" 
Value 0.000000 
start csv 
X " "
PaX "  "
Time " " 
pa " " 
xixj "0-2" 
Value 0.000000 
start csv 
X " "
PaX "  "
Time " " 
pa " " 
xixj "1-0" 
Value 0.000000 
start csv 
X " "
PaX "  "
Time " " 
pa " " 
xixj "1-1" 
Value 0.000000 
start csv 
X " "
PaX "  "
Time " " 
pa " " 
xixj "1-2" 
Value 0.000000 
start csv 
X " "
PaX "  "
Time " " 
pa " " 
xixj "2-0" 
Value 0.000000 
start csv 
X " "
PaX "  "
Time " " 
pa " " 
xixj "2-1" 
Value 0.000000 
start csv 
X " "
PaX "  "
Time " " 
pa " " 
xixj "2-2" 
Value 0.000000
```

and Value is always 0. How can I fix this problem? 
here the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define BUFSIZ 1024

#define ARRAYSIZE(x)  (sizeof(x)/sizeof(*(x)))

double calculateMLpa(const char *Xn_val[], char *traj[], float value[], double alphaxixj, double tauxi, int sz, int dim) {
    double mlx = 0;
    double v;
    double alphaxi;
    char *state;
    int i;
    int p;
    int j;
    int k;
    //  int sz = sizeof(Xn_val) / sizeof(int);
    //  int dim = sizeof(traj) / sizeof(char);
    double trns[sz][sz];
    double m[sz];
    char *trat="-";



    // m[xi] values: the number of transitions leaving the state xi
    printf("%d %d \n",sz,dim);
    int cont=0;
    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        m[i] = 0.0;
        for (j = 0; j < sz; j++) {
            v = 0.0;
            int newlength = strlen(Xn_val[i])+strlen(trat)+strlen(Xn_val[j])+1;
            state = malloc(sizeof(char)*newlength);
            if(state != NULL){
                state[0] = '\0';
                strcat(state,Xn_val[i]);
                strcat(state,trat);
                strcat(state,Xn_val[j]);
                printf("%s ",state);
            }else {
                printf(stderr,"malloc failed!\n");
            }
            //          for (k=0; k<=dim;++k){
            if (traj[cont] != NULL ){
                if (strcmp(traj[cont],state)==0){
                    v = value[cont+1];
                    printf("%f \n",v);
                }
            }

            trns[i][j] = v;

            printf("%f - \n",trns[i][j]);
            if (strcmp(Xn_val[i],Xn_val[j])!=0)
                m[i] = m[i] + v;

            cont++;
        }
    }
    for (i=0;i<sz;++i){
        for(j=0;j<sz;++j){

            printf("%f ",trns[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


    for (p=0;p<sz;++p){
        printf("%f - \n",m[p]);
    }
    alphaxi = alphaxixj * (((double) sz) - 1.0);
    alphaxi = alphaxixj;
    //printf("%d ",sz);
    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < sz; j++) {
            // xi!=xj
            if (strcmp(Xn_val[i], Xn_val[j])!=0) {
                mlx = mlx + lgamma(alphaxixj + trns[i][j]) - lgamma(alphaxixj);
            }
            // xi
            else {
                mlx = mlx + lgamma(alphaxi) - lgamma(alphaxi + m[i]);
                mlx = mlx + lgamma(alphaxi + m[i] + 1.0)+ (alphaxi + 1.0) * log(tauxi);
                mlx = mlx - lgamma(alphaxi + 1.0)- (alphaxi + m[i] + 1.0) * log(tauxi + trns[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    return (mlx);
}

void main() {
    printf("inizio\n");
    FILE *pf;
    int N=20;
    int f,kk=0,k=0,i;
    bool first=true;
    const char *a[]={"0","1","2"};
    char *traject[]={"0-0","0-1","0-2","1-0","1-1","1-2","2-0","2-1","2-2"};
    double bs=0;
    char *str;
    char *trat="-";
    int file;

    //for (file=0;file<4;++file){
    pf=fopen("//home//user//prova0.csv","r");

    //float array[10][10];
    float *t;

    //char *state[];
    t = (float *)malloc(N * sizeof(float));

    float val;
    if (pf)
    {

        char buffer[BUFSIZ], *ptr;
        /*
         * Read each line from the file.
         */
        while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, pf)){
            k++;
        }
        fclose(pf);
        pf=fopen("//home//user//prova0.csv","r");
        printf("k=%d\n",k);
        char *state[k];
        while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, pf)) {
            //k=0;
            printf("start csv \n");
            char *X;
            char *PaX;
            int Time;
            char *pa;
            char *xixj;
            double Value[k];
            char *token;
            char *ptr = buffer;
            const char end[2]=",";//fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, pf);
            token = strtok(ptr, end);
            f=0;
            /* walk through other tokens */
            while( token != NULL )
            {

                if(f==0){
                    X=token;
                    printf( "X %s\n", token );
                }else if(f==1){
                    PaX=token;
                    printf( "PaX %s\n", token );
                }
                else if(f==2){
                    Time=(token);
                    printf( "Time %s \n", token );

                }
                else if(f==3){
                    pa=token;
                    printf( "pa %s \n", token );

                }
                else if(f==4){
                    xixj=(token);
                    printf( "xixj %s \n", token );

                }
                else{
                    char *str;
                    Value[kk]=strtod(token, &str);
                    printf("Value %f \n", Value[kk]);
                    kk++;

                }
                token = strtok(NULL, end);
                f++;

            }

        }


        fclose(pf);
    }

    else /* fopen() returned NULL */
    {
        perror(pf);
    }
        }

    printf("\nstart\n");
    int sz=ARRAYSIZE(a);
    int dim=ARRAYSIZE(traject);
    bs=calculateMLpa(a,traject,t,1.0,0.1,sz,dim);
    printf("done file%d \n",file);
    printf("%f ",bs);
    //}

}
```

Comment: You didn't assign `str` when using `strtod()`, and you passed it a `char**` instead of `char*`.

Comment: @PCLuddite how can I solve this?

Comment: By assigning an appropriate value to `str` and not passing the address of `str` to `strtod()`.

Comment: You also read all the values with ", you need to get rid of them before parsing to double, as I understand.

Comment: I deleted & from str, but I don't know which is the appropriate valuer for str

Comment: @adry_b89 Read [the documentation for strtod()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtod/). It requires a pointer of the character in the string at which to stop, or `NULL`.

Comment: Side note: rather than `t = (float *)malloc(N * sizeof(float));`, consider `t = malloc(sizeof *t * N);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read all the values with ", you need to get rid of them before parsing to double, as I understand.

`xixj "0-1"` and `printf( "xixj %s \n", token );` means token = `<"0-1">`, not `<0-1>`, the same is for value, it is `<"383">` and not `<383>`.

So this should be rather used:

```
Value[kk]=strtod(&token[1], NULL);
```

This:

```
printf("Value %d \n", Value[kk]);
```

should be

```
 printf("Value %f \n", Value[kk]);
```

since Value[k] is double.

And for something completely different - you should really consider working by coding standards, things like one-letter names make code much less maintainable and readable.

Comment: I change this but results are the same

Comment: Sorry for variable name but I was a little confused at the time of declaration. I have change '&str' to 'str' but nothing change.

Comment: str will point to the first char that is not a digit, you can pass null there instead.

Comment: try `Value[kk]=strtod(token[1], null);`

Comment: the execution fails when arrive at 'Value[kk]=strtod(token[1], NULL);' and the value of token is '0x7fffffffd85f "\"Value\"\n"'

Comment: sorry, it should be &token[1]

Answer (score 0):

thanks to  @Roman Pustylnikov  and @PC Luddite the answer is:

```
Value[kk]=strtod(&token[1], NULL);
```

Comment: I had not seen the correction on your answer, sorry. Now I saw and make your